# Tracking and Predicting Movements in Time-Series

Tags: python, machine-learning, time-series, data-science

I have a little project to do and I am having a little difficulty to draw the plan before starting.

I have a database consisting of: **ship name, date time, latitude, longitude**, it's all about tracking the ship movement in the space-time.

the data:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/85a6nj3v19jw9b6/test.png?dl=0

In that case of having a time series, which model you would apply for the problem in order to predict the ship's next destination? the moment when the ship enters/exits a port?

Should I use ARIMA models instead of machine learning algorithms?

and last question: if I don't have the ports names, how can I manually define the ports based on the positions observation?

I have thought of Random Forest but I think there are better models I guess

I would love to have some discussions and argue to see the different point of views, 
and thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about it as a sin wave. To predict sine wave you only need couple of previous values to predict future one. I would use neutral networks for timeseries where input is value x, x-1,x-2 and so on and you train it on value x+2 for example .If you send me some data, I can try to verify this claim

EDIT:

Hi, I am back. I cant give you much. I checked the data and it looks there is so little information for neural network. Moreover the data are quite unprepared with different timestamp gap. Interestingly longitude looks like complete sinewave, but from one sinewave you can really make model. My strategy was to learn neural network on actual and previous values of longitude and latitude for every value in dataset. But even from looking on dataset, I already doubted it could work. Sorry

These are results, but I doubt their significance:

black - original

green - predicted

red - error between original and predicted

**Predicting longitude 100 samples ahead**

[image]

**Predicting longitude 30 samples ahead - looks good, but you dont really need Neural networks for this**

[image]

PS: Ingore that the last value of dataset goes to zero. Its flaw in my program

PS2: In case you are interested in this neural networks for timeseries, they are part of Polynomial neural networks, or HONU neural networks

PS3: Consider using only longitude or latitude to make model. In this data, I got better results excluding latitude

Comment: Can you send me the code that you have used for this answer please? I am sure i can learn loads from that !

Thank you !

Comment: I am sorry, I used gui which I made years ago for those neutral networks. I will try to make a code from it but I don't promise